# Using Selenium and Python pull the list of specific search results based on site name

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am attempting to visit specific sites provided in the search results page.  I can pull back an entire list of sites on the page but 1) it includes sites which are not specific to the one I want to visit and 2) will error out.

```
driver.get('https://www.Google.com')

search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys( sites[site_index] + " " + phones[phone_index] +   " review" )
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(4)
my_search_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc']")
myRandomNumber = random.randint(0, len(my_search_list))
print("this is len list ", len(my_search_list))
print(myRandomNumber)
my_search_list[myRandomNumber].click()
```

Please notice in the above that search.send_keys is specifically entering this text "**The Verge Google Pixel 3 review"**

Here is the page I am trying to pull from.  I want all the websites with The verge.

https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=zbwKXubiFua1tgW0sKHACQ&q=The+Verge+Google+Pixel+3+review&oq=The+Verge+Google+Pixel+3+review&gs_l=psy-ab.3...23.169..180...0.0..0.0.0.......0....1..gws-wiz.1kE53ioW9rU&ved=0ahUKEwim_ZK79d7mAhXmmq0KHTRYCJgQ4dUDCAg&uact=5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added for loop to filter the `my_search_list` array and append the verge results to a new array. Maybe this will get you going in the direction you are trying to go.

```
driver.get('https://www.Google.com')
time.sleep(5)
search = driver.find_element_by_name('q')
search.send_keys("The Verge Google Pixel 3 review")
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(4)
my_search_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc']")
    save_links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='rc']//div//a[contains(@href, 'theverge.com')]")
the_verge_links = []

for link in my_search_list:
    if 'theverge.com' in link.text:
        the_verge_links.append(link)
        time.sleep(2)
        print(link.text)


print("____________________________________________________")
print("____________________________________________________")
myRandomNumber = random.randint(0, len(the_verge_links))
print("this is len list ", len(the_verge_links))
print(myRandomNumber)
# the_verge_links[myRandomNumber].click()

link_text = []
for verge_link in save_links:
    link_text.append(verge_link.get_attribute("href"))

for saved_link_text in link_text:
    driver.get(saved_link_text)
```

Comment: @Normandy to visit each site in the list you can either do the google search again so the link will be able to be clicked on again or you can save all the links you are interested in and use `driver.get()` to get to them.

I'll edited the answer to provide an example.